# Will PDO know if mysql crashed?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

Forgive me if this is a silly question, but I'm in a difficult situation.

does this:

```
$query = "SELECT `av`.`UUID`, `pay`.`amount`, `pay`.`id`
      FROM `2starsglobal`.`avatars` AS av
      RIGHT JOIN `payments` AS `pay` ON `av`.`id` = `pay`.`avatarId`
      WHERE `pay`.`payed` = 0 AND `pay`.`verificationPending` = 0
      ORDER BY `pay`.`id` ASC
      LIMIT 0, 14";

$stmt = $db->query($query);

echo 'SUCCESS';

$payments = "";

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    $payments .= ",{$row[0]},{$row[1]},{$row[2]}";
    //echo ',', $row[0],',', $row[1],',', $row[2];
    $query = "UPDATE `payments` SET `verificationPending`=1 WHERE `id`={$row[2]}"; 
}

try
{
    $db->query($query)->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    return;
}

echo $payments;
```

guarantee that php will handle the case scenario bellow?

We have a payments system for a game, last time we put it out for testing, mysql settings for allocated memory weren't correct, so the db was refusing connections and didn't run the queries as it should, or at least some of them. So the result was, the paid flag in payments table not getting set and payments to be made over and over.

Now this chunk of code up there is what follows the query and a **SUCCESS** message ( for communication ) my idea is if mysql crashes or fails in anyway, not to display the payments that should be made. Will the chunk above work in all cases?

Hope i made myself clear and ty

**edit:**
The code above was written mostly for demonstration, it's not correct code, as I noticed a bit late. But that shouldn't bother you because the original question is. If `PDO` will handle db crashes and all the rest.

my idea is for each Successfully updated row, to `echo` that particular payment, and that's not what the code above does. pretty messed up.

**MORE EDITS**

As you'll notice, I'm eager to get an answer about how safe I am. (I hope it'll have states and facts for the reason why i'm safe or why not) So here it is, what I will probably keep as my code, unless told other wise. Should I feel safe with this?

```
$query = "SELECT `av`.`UUID`, `pay`.`amount`, `pay`.`id`
      FROM `2starsglobal`.`avatars` AS av
      RIGHT JOIN `payments` AS `pay` ON `av`.`id` = `pay`.`avatarId`
      WHERE `pay`.`payed` = 0 AND `pay`.`verificationPending` = 0
      ORDER BY `pay`.`id` ASC
      LIMIT 0, 14";

$stmt = $db->query($query);

$payments = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

$query = "UPDATE `payments` SET `verificationPending`=1 WHERE "; 

foreach($payments as $payment)
{
     $query .= "`id`={$payment[2]} AND "; 
}

$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query-5));

try
{
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $db->query($query)->closeCursor();

    $db->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();
    return;
}

echo "SUCCESS"; 

foreach($payments as $payment)
{
   echo ",{$payment[0]},{$payment[1]},{$payment[2]}";
}
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you should also consider what happens if PHP crashes (eg out of memory).  In my experience this is a LOT more common than MySql crashing.  Transactions help in that case.

Comment: I think here you should be looking at using transactions. Usually if a critical query depends on a previous query it is better to use a transaction, so that if one fails everything is rolled back, and your database will not be disaligned.

Comment: Yup, transactions is a good solution.

Comment: You should also test whether your queries actually affect anything and make sure they do not affect *too much*. Use transactions, then error out if something seems wrong and roll back.

Comment: @GarethL Seems like transactions are winning. And I think that's the way I'll go. But still. Is it 100% or at least 98 hehe, that it will be handled as it should?

Comment: As long as you are careful with your logic (ie: not committing halfway through the transaction), it should be 100% safe - but obviously "100%" is a big claim :)

Comment: After your latest edit, your UPDATE query will not work... you will end up with "WHERE id = 'something' AND id = 'somethingelse' AND id = 'yetanotherthing'. Better to use "WHERE id IN ('something','somethingelse','yetanotherthing',...)

Comment: @GarethL It just worked with 11 payments

Comment: @GarethL But I think I'll change it. That will save me from `substr` and `strlen` and it seems better than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the solution your looking for but you should always be checking your code as you go.  In this instance you want to return success if the record exists...

```
$query = '...';
$stmt = $db->query($query);

if($stmt === false)
    // Query failed to execute

while($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    ...
}

$stmt = $db->query($query);
if($stmt === false)
    // Update failed

$stmt->closeCursor();
// NOW you can echo
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
(PDO returns boolean false if it fails to query)